# How do I average the last 6 months of sales within SQL based on period AND year?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I average the last 6 months of sales within SQL?

Here are my tables and fields:

```
IM_ItemWhseHistoryByPeriod.FISCALCALPERIOD,
IM_ItemWhseHistoryByPeriod.FISCALCALYEAR,
```

And I need to average these fields

```
IM_ItemWhseHistoryByPeriod.DOLLARSSOLD, 
IM_ItemWhseHistoryByPeriod.QUANTITYSOLD,
```

The hard part I'm having is understanding how to average the last whole 6 months, ie. fsicalcalperiod 2-6(inside fiscalcalyear 2017).

I'm hoping for some help on what the SQL command text should look like since I'm very new to manipulating SQL outside of the UI.

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrK5R.jpg)

My Existing SQL String:

```
SELECT IM_ItemWhseHistoryByPeriod.ITEMCODE,
IM_ItemWhseHistoryByPeriod.DOLLARSSOLD, 
IM_ItemWhseHistoryByPeriod.QUANTITYSOLD, 
IM_ItemWhseHistoryByPeriod.FISCALCALPERIOD, 
IM_ItemWhseHistoryByPeriod.FISCALCALYEAR
FROM MAS_AME.dbo.IM_ItemWhseHistoryByPeriod
IM_ItemWhseHistoryByPeriod
```

[ScaisEdge Attempt #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXxm7.jpg)

Comment: Are you looking for the last 6 months from the current date whenever the query is run?

Comment: show a proper data sample (with data type) and the expected  result ..

Comment: I agree you with scaisEdge that you should include sample data and expected result if more than his answer is needed.  AVG() is a simple average function and good for most things but what if your dataset doesn't contain everyday? E.g. what if a store is open but doesn't sell something and there isn't an entry in your table do you need to include a 0 day sale and then average?  These types of nuances are important to note for this type of question.

Comment: I have now included sample data to show what my data on the SQL server looks like, and how I'd like it to look. 

The exact formula for the average we're going for would actually be:
SUM of 6 months - MAX of 6 months / 5 (essentially removing outliers from the average, which also inherently counts months with no sales.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if fiscalyear and fiscalperiod are number you could use

```
  select avg(IM_ItemWhseHistoryByPeriod.DOLLARSSOLD) , 
        avg(IM_ItemWhseHistoryByPeriod.QUANTITYSOLD) 
  from my_table 
  where IM_ItemWhseHistoryByPeriod.FISCALCALYEAR   = 2017
  and IM_ItemWhseHistoryByPeriod.FISCALCALPERIOD between 2 and 6
```

or for each item code

```
  select itemcode, avg(IM_ItemWhseHistoryByPeriod.DOLLARSSOLD) , 
        avg(IM_ItemWhseHistoryByPeriod.QUANTITYSOLD) 
  from my_table 
  where IM_ItemWhseHistoryByPeriod.FISCALCALYEAR   = 2017
  and IM_ItemWhseHistoryByPeriod.FISCALCALPERIOD between 2 and 6 
  group by itemcode
```

Comment: looks like it didn't work. I added a picture to the main question of this attempt.

Comment: show me the error please .. .anyway answer  updated  with missing )

Comment: Labelled the picture ScaisEdge Attempt #1.

Comment: Works like a charm, and I was able to manipulate it easily. Thank you @scaisEdge!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution and see if it works for you:

```
select avg(DOLLARSSOLD) as AvgDollarSod, 
        avg(QUANTITYSOLD) as AvgQtySold
  from IM_ItemWhseHistoryByPeriod
  where FISCALCALYEAR   = '2017
  and FISCALCALPERIOD between 2 and 6
```